# Convention for dummy variables

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis

I have just been introduced to the topic of integration. My teacher said:

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$$

Is the same thing as:

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(\alpha) d\alpha$$

I asked her why, and she said "it is a dummy variable."

But then I thought, are all variables dummy variables? **how do you identify a dummy variable?**

Comment: It's not just about being a "dummy variable". You could take any variable in any mathematical text and swap all instances of it to something else (which has not already been used) and it would retain the same meaning.

Comment: @Regret, why, how?

Comment: Would it sidestep the problem to perform the substitution $x=\alpha$?

Comment: A symbol's job is to represent something. When you have several distinct things in need of representation, you use multiple symbols. It doesn't matter if you use $a,b,c$ or $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$, as long as the meaning of each symbol is clear and they are distinct.

Comment: Just to clarify, in my topmost comment, by "variable" I mean the symbol used to represent the variable.

Comment: userno62593 = anonymous?

Comment: Intuitively, the result of a definite integral is just a number, so it doesn't depend on which variable is being used.

Answer (score 3):

$x$ only has meaning inside the integral, it has no value outside and the result does not depend on it (there is no $x$ in the result). So renaming a variable does nothing, it doesn't even change names of variables in the result.

This becomes even more evident if you remember an integral is just a fancy summation. Consider this sum:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{10} i^2 = 0^2+1^2+2^2+\cdots+10^2=385$$
Of course
$$\sum_{n=0}^{10} n^2 = 0^2+1^2+2^2+\cdots+10^2=385$$
is exactly the same thing. The sum (or the integral) actually does not take one particular value of its "dummy" variable, it is just a name we give the value that sweeps across the entire interval from the lower to the upper limit.

You can easily recognize the dummy variables as those that have a limited scope: those that are undefined outside a local internal part of the expression. Before the integral sign, there is no $x$. Then the integral comes and it says "I will need to remember how far I already integrated - this value, call it $x$ or whatever, will go from $a$ to $b$". Once the integral finishes the job and gives you the answer, its local book-keeping is forgotten.

The concept of scope is very natural in programming: local variables inside a function can be named whatever you want, and different functions can even use the same name for their local variables.

Comment: this is a good answer $(+1)$ out of interest, are you too refering to the definition of the bound variable as ganbustein was?

Comment: Yes, it's the same definition, I just wanted to focus on the more intuitive explanation that I use in class.

Comment: thanks, I was also a little confused about this =)

Answer (score 1):

What the teacher meant was the $x$ (or $a$) was a *bound* variable, used only internally to the expression and having no visibility outside it. For example, it would be nonsense to ask for the value of $$\int_a^b{f(x)\ dx} \quad{\rm when }\ x = 5$$
because the $x$ in the *when* clause is outside the expression, and cannot refer to the $x$ that is bound into, and therefore hidden inside, the expression.

That makes the choice of variable name arbitrary. If it's hidden inside the expression, who outside the expression cares how it's spelled?

Comment: so by **definition** of a bound variable we can change it?

Comment: In your first line, does $a$ refer to the lower limit of the integral?